# eclipse open error failed to find main class in eclipse\\plugins/org...jar

Tags: java, eclipse

at the beginning it says that failed to find java jdk or jre so i installed it. then i run it again it came up this. 
It says that "`Failed to find a Main Class in ... eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar`"

java file are under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31 && jre7
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31 && jre1.8.0_31
```

my eclipse file are under

```
D:\迅雷下载\操作系统\eclipse
```

can someone tell me how to fix this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move **eclipse** to some simpler path, like **D:\development\eclipse**

Comment: it worked when i put it in to D drive but why ? is just a folder name so why can't eclipse over come that ??

Comment: It looks like it can't stand hierogliphs

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have in folder c:\eclipse\2023-03\eclipse (failed), and only move to c:\eclipse\ and works!

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the similar issue where on launching eclipse photon it was giving error like:

> Failed to find a Main Class in ...
>   eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher*.jar

One of the reasons in my case was that I had two JDK versions on my system (JDK 6 & JDK 8).
It was running fine but stopped when I updated JAVA_HOME as JDK 6.

To rectify it, I added the below lines in the `eclipse.ini` file before `-vmargs`:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Basically, I passed the JDK 8 path to the eclipse as required version for eclipse photon was Java 8. And this got me working.

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to because you might have downgraded the version of java in your environmental variables.Try changing the java version in environmental variables and then run the sts or eclipse..for better practice restart the system.hope it helps.!!

Answer (score 1):

I do not mean to steal the first answer - it did help me solve my very similar issue.

I am running Windows 8 x64 bit and installed a modded version of Eclipse in a custom path (rather the default install location that was suggested) - and I got that error.

So, I deleted that Eclipse install. Then installed both x86 and x64 versions of [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (to their default install locations), and repeated the Eclipse install to the default install location - that solved the problem for me!!!

The reason I installed both JDK versions was because I initially installed only the x64 bit version and a different error came. So I removed that Eclipse again, and repeated the JDK with both versions, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I was on this problem for like an hour and a half not getting that **if you save the eclipse file in a non-English named folder it doesn't open.**
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are 2 Java paths mentioned in the system Variable "Path"

If yes, Move up the Java path which is mentioned in JAVA_HOME.

For example:

If `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211`
then the Path should have same Java version's path

```
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
```

In my case I just changed the Path **from**

```
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

**To**

```
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Eclipse from Non English folder if any.

Comment: It did not helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is issue might be because of the folder location or the JDK version,
I installed the latest version JDK and with **eclipse-inst-win64** provided by eclipse i was able to install and run successfully

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens when you change **eclipse.exe** to a different name, seems like **org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar** starts the ide and looks for **eclipse.exe**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Eclipse installer downloaded the wrong VM vertion. I download it separately. Choose it in clause "Java 11+ VM" and it works. Also check you do not have Russian letters in eclipse.ini. If you do, then change the encoding to UTF-8 and write the right letters in Russian.

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer